# Show total and average in matrix widget in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have a matrix visual with on the last row the totals. I would like to know if it's posible to show the average and the totals on the last row like this:

[image: matrix visual with totals and average]

I can only select average or total.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use isinscope and switch GT with Avg.

Another is to add a custom total using extending dimension
https://youtu.be/C9K8uVfthUU